# How do I get my Github branches to match my local branches

Tags: git, github, branch, pull

I have successfully merged a PR from my 'add-new-task-dialog' branch to the 'development' branch. After that I deleted the 'add-new-task-dialog' branch using the Github interface. My local git branches look like this:
[image]

I have just pulled the current code file changes from the github development branch to my local devlopment branch using git pull. Now that my development branch code matches, how do I get the branches to match? I just want my local to match everything on github.

The Github branches currently looks like this:
[image]

Comment: They will be listed as remote branches : `git branch -r`. Run `git fetch --prune` if you want to delete branches that don't exist anymore in your central repo.

Answer (score 1):

People like to think of branches as global.  That is, there's some Source of Truth repository, perhaps on GitHub; whatever is in it, those *are* the branches in the project.

In some systems (e.g., Mercurial), they really *are* global.  This is a problem with a *distributed* version control system, though.  To make a new branch, you would have to go to GitHub and do it.  The Mercurial solution here was that you could create a new branch locally, and it would then spread, virus-like, to every other repository.  Soon everyone had [billions of branches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billions_and_Billions), and the system was quite unusable.  OK, not really: people exercised restraint—sometimes—and the Source of Truth repository managers would strip out bad branches and so on, but the sad reality is that this technique just does not scale.

Git's answer is simple: your branches are *yours*.  Their branches are *theirs*.  Your branches are not theirs, and theirs are not yours.  You can have one branch, or ten, or billions: GitHub's repository is unchanged.  Whoever manages the GitHub repository may create and delete branches at will, and *your* repository is unchanged.

Humans being human, however, we sometimes *want* our branches to spread like the Rona.  Meanwhile other people are out there killing them off.  I take no sides in this branch war (unlike the one with the Rona).  What I can tell you is that in Git, to avoid branches going viral, your own Git:

- reads their Git's *branch names*, and
- *changes* those into *remote-tracking names*.<sup>1</sup>

(When I say "your Git" I mean "your Git software working in your repository clone".  Likewise, their Git is their software, working in their clone.)  This renaming happens during `git fetch`.

If you use `git pull`, you're really just telling Git to run two Git commands:

- First, run `git fetch`.
- Then, based on what `git fetch` fetched, run a second command.

The `fetch` step will do this renaming.  The second command will work on your *current branch*.  (You often will want to run some second command—usually either `git merge` or `git rebase`—which is when and why it's good to be able to do those with one command.  But sometimes you might want to *see* what `git fetch` fetched, before you decide which second command, if any, to run.  That's when and why it's *bad* to *have* to do those with one command.  I recommend learning to use each command first, *then* deciding on what to run.  But that's a separate topic.)

A *remote-tracking name* is just a branch name with `origin/`, or something similar, shoved in front of it.<sup>2</sup>  This `origin`-or-similar is literally a *remote:* a short name by which your Git refers to some other Git.  Running `git clone URL-of-GitHub-repository` creates a new repository on your own machine—e.g., your laptop—and *remembers* the URL, under the short name `origin`, which is the default standard first name for "the (single) other Git repository".

Since their branch names are *theirs*, to do with as they will, your Git takes their branch names and sticks `origin/`—using the remote name—in front of each one, to remember that those are *theirs*.  The result of this `git clone` operation is that you have a new repository that has all of their *commits*, but *no branches at all yet*.  Instead of branch names, you just have these remote-tracking names.

That's not good, so as its last act, `git clone` makes *one* branch name in your repository.  The one branch name it makes is the one you choose, with your `-b` option.  If you don't choose one, your Git asks their Git for a recommendation.  Their Git will usually recommend `main` or `master`: whatever you see as the "default" over on GitHub.

Your Git then makes this as a branch name in *your* repository, using, as its last commit, the same commit that is the last commit on *their* branch of the same name, which is now a remote-tracking name in *your* repository.  So you now have one branch that matches one of their branches, via one of your remote-tracking names, which remember their branches.  (Whew!)

Note that `git push` does not do this funky renaming.  You run `git fetch` and your Git goes over to `origin` and lists out their branch names and makes remote-tracking names, `origin/*`, for their branch names.  But when you run `git push`, you pick *one* branch name:

```
git push origin add-new-task-dialog
```

for instance.  This syntax is short for:

```
git push origin add-new-task-dialog:add-new-task-dialog
```

The name on the left, `add-new-task-dialog`, is the name that `git push` uses in *your* repository to find the commit(s) to send to their Git.  The name on the *right*, `add-new-task-dialog` again, is the name your Git asks their Git to *create or update* in *their* repository.  They don't rename this!  They take whatever name you ask them to set as-is.

You can, if you like, use different names in your repository and theirs:

```
git push origin hello:world
```

uses your branch name `hello` to get the commits to send, but ends by asking them to create or update their branch name `world`.  Mostly this just makes for confusion, but if you start using *two* remotes, you may eventually find that you need to use a different name on *your* side than for at least one branch name on "their" sides.

In any case, all of this renaming and remote-tracking-name stuff works pretty well, except for one flaw.  Suppose you run `git fetch origin` and, right at this very moment, they have a temporary branch named `temp-branch`.  Your Git will see this and create `origin/temp-branch` in *your* repository.  Meanwhile, time passes: maybe a second, or even longer!  The temporary branch is now *gone:* you run `git fetch` again and they don't have a `temp-branch`.  Your Git doesn't rename their `temp-branch` to `origin/temp-branch`, so it doesn't create or update your `origin/temp-branch` this time.

But you *already have* `origin/temp-branch`, from the *earlier* fetch operation.  Just because you didn't create or update it *now*, a few seconds later, doesn't make it *go away*.  It probably should: the point of your remote-tracking names is, after all, to remember *their* Git's *branch* names, and now that name is gone.  Your Git should stop remembering this stale branch.  But when remote-tracking names were invented, back in 2007 or so, whoever invented them did not think to do it this way.

Git is pretty serious about backwards compatibility, so 2021 Git *still* does not do this by default.  You can, however, tell Git to do it: `git fetch --prune`, or `git remote update --prune`, tells your Git to go out to a remote (`git fetch`) or a group of remotes (`git remote update`) and this time, if they *don't* have some branch, delete (prune away) remote-tracking names that are obviously stale like this.

You can also *configure* your Git to make this the default.  The `fetch.prune` setting, in your per-repository and/or global (user-wide) Git configuration, controls whether `git fetch` acts like `git fetch --prune` *by default*.  Simply run:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

to set this in your per-user configuration and `git fetch` will default to pruning away stale remote-tracking names.  (Since `git pull` *runs* `git fetch`, this affects `git pull` as well.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but the word *branch* here is redundant and misleading: you cannot get "on" one of these, the way you get "on a branch" with `git checkout` or `git switch`.  Try `git checkout origin/development` some time, or `git switch origin/development`.  Note that the two commands act rather differently here.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the remote-tracking names are in a separate [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), so if you make a *branch* name starting with `origin/`, it's still a *branch* name, not a remote-tracking name.  Don't do this: it will only serve to confuse you.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, there seems to be a lot of ruin in git branches.  Would it be a good policy to not have local branches?  I.e. create all branches in the GitHub repo, and just clone with -b to different directories locally.  Each local copy of the project would thus track one, and only one, remote branch.